# XPath element number returns all elements instead than first

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am using the following code to access a link (for phpunit/selenium):

```
//td[normalize-space() ='Test title 2']/following-sibling::td[3]/a[.='delete']
```

using an XPath checker in FireFox it returns 7 elements (because there are 7 links matching "test title 2"), but when I add `[1]` at the end:

```
//td[normalize-space() ='Test title 2']/following-sibling::td[3]/a[.='delete'][1]
```

it still returns 7 links. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Btw, selenium will access only one link by default (the first link from seven links occurrences). What are you trying to do?

Comment: test that a delete button works- one that was generated from a previous test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add `[1]` in the end of your expression, you select the first `a` child of each `...td[3]` (i.e. 7 `a` child nodes). You can change your query to:

```
xpath=(//td[normalize-space() ='Test title 2']/following-sibling::td[3]/a[.='delete'])[1]
```

or in case you use webdriver (xpath prefix is not needed):

```
(//td[normalize-space() ='Test title 2']/following-sibling::td[3]/a[.='delete'])[1]
```

This will select the first `a` from the entire set of `a` children of `...td[3]` elements.

Refer to [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) for more tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

As [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) says:

> The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location
>   path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant
>   `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are
>   the first `para` children of their parents.

Therefore,

```
//td[normalize-space() ='Test title 2']/following-sibling::td[3]/descendant::a[.='delete'][1]
```

will do a better job in your case.

Comment: Notice that spec says about `//para[1]` but not `/para[1]`.

Comment: So `/descendant::td[normalize-space()='Test title 2'][1]/following-sibling::td[3]/a[.='delete']` will be more correct.